# Probabilistic Robotics: Map-based motion model

Tags: localization, probability

[I asked the following question in math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344912/pab-c-pab-pac), but realized that this might be the more appropriate place to post it: How did Thrun derive the following formula: [(Context here)](https://books.google.de/books?id=2Zn6AQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA140&ots=vHnEODAD_A&dq=probabilistic%20robotics%205.48&pg=PA140#v=onepage&q=probabilistic%20robotics%205.48&f=false)

[image]

I think that this formula might either be wrong or make assumptions that are not guarantueed to be true (like statistical independence), but am not sure which ones exactly. Any pointers are welcome :)

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Thomas, but I'm afraid that [cross-posting the same question to multiple sites is not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/138432). If you find a better place to ask your question, please do not just ask your question a second time, instead flag it to a moderator who can migrate the question for you. Questions which would not be considered on topic on the target site will not be migrated.

Comment: See [P(A|B,C)=P(A|B)∗P(A|C)∗
…?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2344912/9281) on [maths.se].

Comment: Have you read chapter 2? Jumping to chapter 5 and claiming the authors make a mistake is a careless mistake, I presume.